# Stopping an Android Service from within a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I have a Service which starts a thread during `onCreate()`. The thread is monitoring hardware (IOIO) and will end once it is disconnected so essesentially is an infinite loop. Stopping the service from an Activity works fine and the thread also stops (ended in `onDestory()`).

My problem is that if the thread dies (say because of an exception) is it possible to stop the service that spawned it.

I've tried using `stopSelf()` from within the thread code but the service does not stop.

Thank you
ps my first post so please excuse any missing conventions I should have followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want here might be to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Eseentially, create a handler for your Sevrice (make sure it's final so you can use across all threads). Then in your other thread, call:

```
myServiceHandler.post(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    stopSelf();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried this solution. However, I can see that the stopSelf() is executed from the msin thread... but nothing happens. And afterwards the service still responds to intents. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the Intent of the service and stopping it directly?
In the service:

```
private Intent thisIntent;

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    thisIntent = intent;
```

In the thread inside the service:

```
stopService(thisIntent);
```